# Connect excel to access to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, microsoft-access

Im trying to sync excel and Sharepoint so I can update an excel table and changes appears in sharepoint. Since I’m using 2016 versions for excel and Sharepoint I noticed it’s not as easy because I need a third party to do a 2-way sync. I came up with the idea of connecting excel to access and acces to Sharepoint. I was able to sync excel with access and access with Sharepoint. The problem is when trying to link excel  to access table and that same access table link it to sharepoint. Doing that I lose the link between excel and access but if I update table in access it appears updated in Sharepoint. It is possible to have two links to the same table in access. What I am doing wrong? I think this is a simple way; otherwise I’ll need PHP, Javascript, ODBC, ActiveXObject, etc. Any help will be great!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you want to sync data in excel file to SharePoint list.

As we know, Microsoft Excel works in one way: it doesn’t sync the data back to SharePoint. It only retrieves it.

Here is a workaround to use Access instead of Excel, then we can sync the list data with Access file. Here are the detail steps:

1. Go to your list, then click Actions > Open with Access. Click OK on popup window, the Microsoft Access open.
2. Edit the Access file, save the file, then all changes will update to calendar list automatically. 
   (We can Import data from Excel to the Access file  by right clicking the calendar table in Access > select Import from Excel.)

Or use Excel Add-in to sync Excel file with SharePoint list.

Reference:

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/09/24/sharepoint-how-to-add-events-into-a-calendar-using-microsoft-excel-and-access-aspx/